# Rails scope doesn't return correct data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I use scope which I prepared in model, rails returns incorrect data.

My Model:

```
class CurrencyRate < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :eur_today, -> {where(currency: "eur").where(date: Time.now.in_time_zone.to_date).first}
end
```

Inforamation from rails console:

```
2.3.0 :011 > CurrencyRate.eur_today

CurrencyRate Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "currency_rates".* FROM 
"currency_rates" WHERE "currency_rates"."currency" = ? AND 
"currency_rates"."date" = ?  ORDER BY "currency_rates"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  
[["currency", "eur"], ["date", "2017-08-09"]]
CurrencyRate Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "currency_rates".* FROM 
"currency_rates"

 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<CurrencyRate id: 2, currency: "eur", 
 sale: 4.248546249999998, purchase: 4.265333125, date: "2017-08-08", 
 created_at: "2017-08-08 20:52:08", updated_at: "2017-08-08 20:54:10", 
 sale_percentage_diff: nil, purchase_percentage_diff: nil>]>
```

When I use the same query like in scope, returned data is correct:

```
2.3.0 :012 > CurrencyRate.where(currency: "eur").where(date: Time.now.in_time_zone.to_date).first 

CurrencyRate Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "currency_rates".* FROM 
"currency_rates" WHERE "currency_rates"."currency" = ? AND 
"currency_rates"."date" = ?  ORDER BY "currency_rates"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  
[["currency", "eur"], ["date", "2017-08-09"]]

=> nil
```

Why scope doesn't work correct?

Comment: Your scope is not a real scope because it returns the first found CurrencyRate record. Remove that `.first` in your scope. You can see in your IRB that there are 2 generated SQL queries, one with the limit 1 (because of your `.first`) and another just doing "select all from current_rates"

Comment: I understand it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Because scopes must return an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. Get rid of the `first` call in your scope and use that outside the scope. Why? Because scopes have to be chainable.

Comment: or just make it a class instance method e.g. `def self.eur_today` since the "scope" name seems to suggest the intention is to return the rate of the Euro as of today. Although I would probably make this `def self.currency_value(currency,as_of=Time.now.in_time_zone.to_date)` so that it can be reused better

Comment: Yep, that's an alternative

Comment: I tried both ways. I understand now how scopes work. Thanks.